# Convert aggregate function from R to python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have a R's aggregate function:

```
usefulTopics = aggregate(Count ~ ID1 + Topic1 + ID2 + Topic2, data = usefulTopics, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I want to convert this code to python and get the dataframe. How can I do so?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
usefulTopics = usefulTopics.groupby('Count')['ID1', 'Topic1', 'ID2', 'Topic2'].agg('sum')
```